# Moving content template to resources in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Trying to move styling/content template to resources of the XAML to get a better overview. 
I have trouble to move this content template to resources.
I think I have not yet wrapped my head around WPF template structure.

```
<controls:CheckCombo 
    Items="{Binding Brands}"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBrands}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <controls:CheckCombo.ButtonContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="80" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:CheckCombo.ButtonContentTemplate>
</controls:CheckCombo>
```

I would like to move it to the beginning of XAML resources similar to this.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate" DataType="controls:CheckCombo">
            <StackPanel Width="80" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: `DataTemplate x:Key="BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate"` is already moved to Resources. just apply it using `{StaticResource BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate}`

Comment: Ok, where do I specify this static resource?  In my case it is a drop down combobox where you click on a button to get items of the list. Idea is to style the button itself.

Comment: don't know what is `controls:CheckCombo `, but valid xaml for attribute is : `<controls:CheckCombo ButtonContentTemplate="{StaticResource BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate}" .../>`. and remove `<controls:CheckCombo.ButtonContentTemplate> .. </controls:CheckCombo.ButtonContentTemplate>`

Comment: You create a dependencyproperty in CheckCombo and then you can assign it like this: <controls:CheckCombo ButtonContentTemplate="{StaticResource BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate}"/>, just like @ASh said. do you need a code example for this? or try googling it

Comment: Yes, thank you both. As you mentioned I needed to use the content template attribute `<controls:CheckCombo ButtonContentTemplate="{StaticResource BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

We have to use Datatemplate in Control

```
<controls:CheckCombo 
Items="{Binding Brands}"
SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBrands}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate}"
DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

[data-templating-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: I went through this link, for this control there is no ItemTemplate property. In my case it is a drop down combobox where you click on a button to get items of the list. Idea is to style the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments, this is the result.

In resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate" DataType="controls:CheckCombo">
            <StackPanel Width="80" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In control:

```
<controls:CheckCombo 
    Items="{Binding Brands}"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedBrands}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    ButtonContentTemplate="{BrandFilterButtonContentTemplate}" />
</controls:CheckCombo>
```